# Firebase error: Uncaught TypeError: ref.once is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase to upload a file as well as enter the file in my data base at the same time. (I would like to keep track of how many uploads there are so I can rename the file to something unique) I successfully uploaded, and also put a copy in the database but I can not get a number back of how many files are in the child folder using the once() and getChildren() methods.  I keep getting an error. What am I doing wrong?  The count number error is coming from **here:**

```
var ref = firebase.database();
                          ref.once("value")
                            .then(function(snapshot) {
                              var numberSamples = snapshot.child(sampleType).numChildren(); //number of children
                            });
```

**Full code:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
            <script>
              // Initialize Firebase
              var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyC9jUMxOvvdgcBvXecvpRiactG6ffbwTgg",
                authDomain: "instasample-d8eea.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://instasample-d8eea.firebaseio.com",
                storageBucket: "instasample-d8eea.appspot.com",
              };
              firebase.initializeApp(config);

              //remove error on click
              function removeSampleClass() {
                $("#sampleType").removeClass('sampleTypeError')
                $("#sampleType").addClass('sampleType')
              }

              function removeFileClass() {
                $("#fileButton").removeClass('fileButtonError')
                $("#fileButton").addClass('fileButton')
              }


              // upload files and check for errors
              function uploadFile(){   //on GO
                  //get elements
                  var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader')
                  var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton')
                  //var file = fileButton.target.files[0]; //get file
                  var sampleType = document.getElementById('sampleType').options[document.getElementById('sampleType').selectedIndex].text;  //get folder location
                  var file = fileButton.files[0]; //get file

                  if (sampleType == "Select Type" && fileButton.value == "") {  //check both selection
                    $("#sampleType").addClass('sampleTypeError')
                    $("#sampleType").removeClass('sampleType')
                    $("#fileButton").addClass('fileButtonError')
                    $("#fileButton").removeClass('fileButton')
                  }
                  else if (fileButton.value == "") {                            //check file selection
                    $("#fileButton").addClass('fileButtonError')
                    $("#fileButton").removeClass('fileButton')
                  }
                  else if (sampleType == "Select Type") {                       //check sample selection
                   $("#sampleType").addClass('sampleTypeError')
                    $("#sampleType").removeClass('sampleType')
                  }
                  else{    //upload if good
                  uploader.classList.remove('hide');  //unhide progress bar
                  //create storage reference with sampleType 
                  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/" + sampleType + "/" + file.name);


                  //upload file
                  var task = storageRef.put(file);

                  //update progress bar
                  task.on('state_changed',
                    function progress(snapshot){
                        var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                        uploader.value = percentage;
                    },
                    function error() {
                      alert('There was a problem uploading your file')
                    },
                    function complete() {
                      //get root reference
                      const dbRefType = firebase.database().ref().child(sampleType);

                      var ref = firebase.database();
                          ref.once("value")
                            .then(function(snapshot) {
                              var numberSamples = snapshot.child(sampleType).numChildren(); // 2 ("first", "last")
                            });


                      var updates = {};
                        updates["/" + sampleType + "/" + sampleType + "Sample" + numberSamples ] = numberSamples;
                        return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
                      //sync data and return children of sampleType to console
                      //dbRefType.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));
                      //create new reference to file
                      //var sampleFileRef = dbRefType.child("sample");


                      //TODO: list how many are in list 
                      //add new file to list


                    }
                  );
                }
              }


            </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, I got it. used

```
dbRefType.once('value', function(snapshot) { alert('Count: ' + snapshot.numChildren()); });
```